# SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown Not Saving Value in IE

Tags: jquery, spservices, internet-explorer

ok, first off this works in FF, Chrome and Safari, but does not work in IE.

- What I am doing is converting the complex dropdown to a simple
  dropdown using SPServices
- Auto-populating the projects column with a querystring parameter

Here is the code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>                   
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown({
            columnName: "Project"
        });    

        function getQuerystring(key, default_)
        {
          if (default_== null) default_=""; 
          key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
          var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&amp;]"+key+"=([^&amp;#]*)");
          var qs = regex.exec(unescape(window.parent.location.href));
          if(qs == null)
            return default_;
          else
            return qs[1];
        }           

        var proj = getQuerystring('proj');

        //var list = document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_dd8909e5_25f4_49a8_b1d6_229952d5ab91_ff101_ctl00_Lookup');
        $('#ctl00_m_g_dd8909e5_25f4_49a8_b1d6_229952d5ab91_ff101_ctl00_Lookup option:contains(' + proj + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');

        if($.browser.msie){
            //var list = document.getElementById('SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_Project');

            $('#SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_Project option:contains(' + proj + ')').attr('selected', 'selected');
            var selectedVal = $('#SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_Project option:contains(' + proj + ')').val();
            alert(selectedVal);

            //set the complex dropdowns value 
            $('#ctl00_m_g_dd8909e5_25f4_49a8_b1d6_229952d5ab91_ff101_ctl00_ctl01').val(selectedVal);
        }//end if


        });
    </script>
```

Again, it works great, accept in IE.  I know that the problem lies within assigning the value to the sharepoint complex dropdown.  but now sure how to set that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you can use [$().SPServices.SPGetQueryString](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetQueryString) rather than rolling your own Query String parser. Secondly, you should be able to just set the simple select and not worry about the hidden complex select. The $().SPServices.SPComplexToSimpleDropdown function takes care of updating the complex select under the covers. Finally, you shouldn't need any different logic for IE than the other browsers.

Comment: would it be actually that being hidden in IE particularly is doesn't return value?

Comment: It's possible that you will have to fire the change event on the simple select manually after setting it. It certainly can't hurt.

Comment: is there any documentation on the change event? how can I fire?

Comment: Have a look here http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: <select>
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
</select>

$('select').val('1'); // selects "Two"
$('select').val('Two'); // also selects "Two"

Try to set the value to something fixed to make sure that the selected item is set, prior to setting it dynamically!

Comment: .trigger('change') - not sure how to use this to make it all work, any thoughts....

Comment: It'll be something like $("#SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_Project").change();

Comment: $("#SPComplexToSimpleDropdown_Project").trigger("change"); makes it work!! thanks for your help guys!!

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this exact problem for weeks! What a relief!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Selected using

$('#ctl00_m_g_dd8909e5_25f4_49a8_b1d6_229952d5ab91_ff101_ctl00_ctl012[value=selectedVal]').attr('selected',true);

Comment: This did not work